# Add Index arn in DynamoDB to sam yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am trying access my DynamoDB via a user that has all access to the table.

However I am failing to query the LSI for the same table. It says user doesn't have permissions to query index.

I checked the documentation and it shows that index needs to be define separately like arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/index/index-name

However I am not sure how to define this in cloudformation yml file.

```
BooksTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName:
        Fn::Sub: ${SamStackPrefix}${Stage}-BooksTable
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: hashKey
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: rangeKey
          KeyType: RANGE
      LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: LSI1
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: hashKey
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: clientToken
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: hashKey
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: rangeKey
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: clientToken
          AttributeType: S
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: expirationTime
        Enabled: true

Outputs:

BooksTableName:
    Description: books table.
    Value:
      !Ref BooksTable
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${SamStackPrefix}${Stage}-BooksTableName
BooksTableArn:
    Description: Arn for books DynamoDB Table
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ BooksTable, Arn ]
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${SamStackPrefix}${Stage}-BooksTableArn
BooksTableStreamArn:
    Description: The DDB stream for the books table.
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt: [BooksTable, StreamArn]
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${SamStackPrefix}${Stage}-BooksStreamArn
```

IAM policy right now

```
Policies:
      - PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Action: ['dynamodb:PutItem', 'dynamodb:ConditionCheckItem', 'dynamodb:Query', 'dynamodb:GetItem', 'dynamodb:UpdateItem']
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - Fn::GetAtt: [BooksTable, Arn]
```

How to add LSI to the list of resources so that I can use that ARN to add permissions in the policy document.

Comment: This is only the table. What is the iam policy that has no access?

Comment: Added IAM policy

Comment: If you have the base table's ARN, then you have most of the LSI's ARN. You just need to append the /index/<your index name here> for specific indexes

Answer (score 1):

Update IAM policy
this should work

```
 Policies:
   - PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Action: ['dynamodb:PutItem', 'dynamodb:ConditionCheckItem', 'dynamodb:Query', 'dynamodb:GetItem', 'dynamodb:UpdateItem']
        Effect: Allow
        Resource:
          - Fn::GetAtt: [BooksTable, Arn]
          - "arn:aws:dynamodb:{region}:{account}:table/{tableName}/index/{indexName}"
```